# HttpConnection through GPRS (Mobile Network)

Tags: java, blackberry

I tried to make HttpConnection of URL through GPRS (Mobile network) on real device but it doesn't return data, but  I the same code working well through wireliess, the code also working well on simulator
My code is

```
public static String getHttpUTFResponse(String url) {
    HttpConnection connection = null;
    byte responseData[] = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpConnection) new ConnectionFactory()
                .getConnection(url).getConnection();
        int len = (int) connection.getLength();
        System.out.println(len);
        if (len != -1) {
            responseData = new byte[len];
            DataInputStream dis;
            dis = new DataInputStream(connection.openInputStream());
            dis.readFully(responseData);
            dis.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Error");
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connection = null;
        }

    }
    if (responseData != null) {
        try {
            return new String(responseData,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: the device browser working well and BB service was registered
Thanks to any one

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Are you getting any exception ? what is line number ?

Comment: It hangs-up on this line, int len = (int) connection.getLength(); after that len returns with (-1) and I gotten no exception

Comment: Are you suffixing `";deviceside=false;connectionUID="` for **BIS** and 
`";deviceside=false"` for **BES** to the connection URL ?

Comment: Try these links [1](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Need-Clarification-Http-Connection-GPRS/td-p/399320), [2](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB20457), [3](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Internet-Connectivity-APN/m-p/1260291), [4](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tag/APN/tg-p)

Comment: Good, were any of my links helpful ? If so let me know the correct link that solved the problem

Comment: This link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879      Thanks again

Comment: Most welcome, i have posted my links as answer kindly mark it as accepted to help future readers of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am moving my comments to these answer:

In Blackberry setting up the connection url for `wireless / gprs / 3g / simulator` is pretty challenging, please follow the below pointers

1. For `WiFi` on device, make sure you have suffixed `";interface=wifi"` to the connection url
2. For `GPRS / 3G` on device, make sure you have suffixed `";deviceside=false;connectionUID="` for **BIS** and `";deviceside=false"` for **BES** to the connection URL

More descriptive explanation can be found at:

1. [Need Clarification ---- Http Connection/GPRS](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Need-Clarification-Http-Connection-GPRS/td-p/399320)
2. [How to configure an IT Policy on the BlackBerry Enterprise Server to allow only the Internet Browser on the BlackBerry smartphone](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB20457)
3. [Internet Connectivity (APN?)](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Internet-Connectivity-APN/m-p/1260291)
4. [Tag: APN](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tag/APN/tg-p)
5. [Different ways to make an HTTP or socket connection](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879)

**EDIT:** Link 5 was useful for OP

Answer (score 0):

try this.. 
this will help you to detect the simulator, wifi and gprs connection

```
getWap2Uid();
            String url = "your url";

            if(DeviceInfo.isSimulator() == true)
            {
                conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url+ ";deviceside=true");
            }
            else
            {
            if (uid != null) 
            {
                //open a WAP 2 connection
                conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url + ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=" + uid);

            }
            else 
            {
                //Consider another transport or alternative action.
                conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url +";deviceside=true;interface=wifi");


            }
            }
```

getWap2Uid function is here

```
public static String uid ; 

static String getWap2Uid() {

    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().findRecordsByCid("WPTCP");
    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
    {
        ServiceRecord serviceRecord = records[i];
        String recordName = serviceRecord.toString().toUpperCase();
        if (serviceRecord.isValid() && !serviceRecord.isDisabled() &&
                serviceRecord.getUid() != null && serviceRecord.getUid().length() != 0 &&
                recordName.indexOf("WAP2")!=-1)

        {
             uid = serviceRecord.getUid();
               EventLogger.logEvent(EventLogID, new String("getWap2Uid, UID="+uid).getBytes() );
            return uid;
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```